# Me myself or I which do I use

Tags: grammar

My friend and I were having a dispute about when to use “me” correctly in a sentence that’s referring to two people. I said that you say " my friends and I" but my friend argued and said " me and my friends" is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to the strict correctness note that the pronoun **I** is used when it is the subject and the pronoun **me** is used when it is the object:

> My friend and I came home.

Here it acts as the subject.

> They saw my friend and me.

Here it acts as the object.